# How to give widget look to the application developed using tide sdk

Tags: html, css, tidesdk

I have developed a weather application for windows using html and css with the help of tide sdk.But i want to give it a widget look like windows desktop gadgets i.e i do not want the title bar and borders that windows applications normally have.

Secondly,please tell me the way of removing application from statusbar i.e its name should not be shown in status bar when application is running,similar to desktop gadgets.I can't figure out how to do this using tide.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"There are two types of transparency in TideSDK. Full window transparency specified with the transparency property and background transparency specified with the transparent-background property."

Look at the example at the very bottom of this page 
http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started